# How to set textcolor of a textview in table layout

Tags: android

In Table layout setting textview textcolor `textViewOdometerReadingData1
                            .setTextColor(color.red);`
but it is showing in gray color.what ever color i used, it is showing in gray color only.
Help me thanks.

Comment: Share some more code, cause on an normal textView this works for me.

Comment: nothing special here,created table layout programmatically ,in a row added textview ,for that i want use custom color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change:

```
textViewOdometerReadingData1.setTextColor(Color.red);
```

and you can also use this:

```
textViewOdometerReadingData1 .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What i found with your code snippet is

```
textViewOdometerReadingData1 .setTextColor(color.red);
```

It should be

```
textViewOdometerReadingData1 .setTextColor(Color.red);
```

Comment: i am using custom color

Comment: Thats the problem i think. You need to be more specific while asking a question. Where you have specified that you are using Custom Color in your question??? People should imagine that you are using Custom Color??

Comment: i think color.red is okay,because for setting background using this and it works for me,,textViewOdometerReadingData1
       .setBackgroundResource(color.green);

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:
For setting text color
textViewOdometerReadingData1.setTextColor(Color.Red);

Answer (score 0):

Not just the 'C' is capital, but the 'RED' too.

```
   textViewOdometerReadingData1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```